# Populating a Combo Box with multiple fields of data from a database

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to populate a combobox with data from a database - using sql. I am trying to use information from multiple fields (First Name, Last Name). I need the program to concatenate the fields and add the 'FullName' into the combobox. Here is the code that I am using - im getting an error as where the names should appear instead appears **"System.Data.DataRowView"**:

```
Private Sub frmViewEmployee_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = "SELECT [First Name], [Last Name] FROM [EmployeeAccounts]"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "EmployeeName")
    Dim x As Short = 0
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim LastName As String
    Dim MaxRows As Short = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows.Count
    Dim FullName(MaxRows) As String
    x = 0
    While x < MaxRows
        FirstName = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows(x).Item(0)
        LastName = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows(x).Item(1)
        FullName(x) = FirstName & " " & LastName
        x = x + 1
    End While
        comEmployeeName.DataSource = ds.Tables(CStr("EmployeeName"))
        comEmployeeName.DisplayMember = CStr(FullName(x))
        comEmployeeName.ValueMember = CStr(FullName(x))
End Sub
```

Any answers, within reason, are appreciated - whether that be corrections or new code entirely.

Comment: Which line is causing the issue?                                                               Try this `FirstName = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows(x).Item(0).ToString`
 `LastName = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows(x).Item(1).ToString`

Comment: This correct an error, now I am receiving: Additional information: Cannot bind to the new display member on the following line: comEmployeeName.ValueMember = CStr(FullName(x))

Comment: UPDATE: I have corrected the original issue, now in the combobox all of the data appears as: System.Data.DataRowView - any idea to why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to change your sql:

```
"SELECT [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] As Fullname FROM [EmployeeAccounts]"
```

And then set Fullname as your Displaymember.

Comment: This looks like a better way to tackle the problem, however I am unsure of what code to remove/ edit in order for this to work - could you re-rewrite mine with your corrections? Would help significantly.

Comment: You only have one SQL Statement in your code.. I thought it would be self-explanatory where to put this line..

Comment: My answer actually required you to understand what you are doing and required you to put it on the correct position instead of making an easy copy pasterino solution

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT [First Name] & ' ' & [Last Name] As Fullname FROM [EmployeeAccounts]"
```

Change your plus to & as vb.net prefers them over +

Comment: No that doesn't make sense as the + ' ' + from my answer is SQL Syntax and not VB.NET.

Comment: i have realised my mistake, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I would make this column a hidden column and then have another column with the concatenated string.

When you are setting the displaymember field on the combobox that is what it display on screen and you seem to set that after you declar the cell contents in the loop. My educated guess is it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

[Not tested]
Depending on DBMS you are working with, you could add a new field in your sql sentence that will be a concatenation of first name and last name.
Something like:

```
sqlstatement = "SELECT [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] as FullName, [First Name], [Last Name] FROM [EmployeeAccounts]"

' It could be another syntax, it depends on your DBMS
sqlstatement = "SELECT [First Name] || ' ' || [Last Name] as FullName, [First Name], [Last Name] FROM [EmployeeAccounts]"
```

And then just set the ValueMember and DisplayMember to FullName:

```
comEmployeeName.DisplayMember ="FullName"
comEmployeeName.ValueMember="FullName"
```

No need for this part of code:

```
While x < MaxRows
    FirstName = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows(x).Item(0)
    LastName = ds.Tables("EmployeeName").Rows(x).Item(1)
    FullName(x) = FirstName & " " & LastName
    x = x + 1
End While
```